# Why doesn't the latest Ubuntu edition come with the latest stable Linux kernel version?

Tags: kernel, release-management

I have recently noticed that the latest version of Ubuntu does not come with the latest stable Linux kernel version.

For example, Kubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with Kernel 4.4.0-21-generic while the latest stable kernel version is 4.5.2.

There is surely a strong reason why they don't ship the OS with the latest stable kernel which is something I would like to learn about.

I would also like to know if updating the kernel to its latest stable edition is a bad idea or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Like Ubuntu, the Linux kernel also has [long-term support versions](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html). So, for an Ubuntu LTS release (like 16.04), picking the latest *long-term* kernel version makes sense. This way, unlike with a normal stable release, Canonical can rely on the kernel maintainers to backport fixes for a long time. 4.4 will be supported till February 2018.

Canonical did pick [a normal stable version, 3.13,](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTUyMTA) for Ubuntu 14.04. This was considered [a mistake](https://tim.siosm.fr/blog/2014/04/25/why-not-ubuntu-14.04-lts/). The Ubuntu community and Canonical devs had to pick up maintenance of the 3.13 kernel [the same month that 14.04 released](https://lwn.net/Articles/595813/). On the other hand, 3.12 would have been supported by the kernel team until next year.

Comment: As well as the issue of newly found problems getting back-ported fixes for longer in certain versions, you need to consider the length of time the final testing phase before a release takes. If a new LTS kernel release were made once that phase had begun it would be foolhardy to drop it into the release - you would either keep the current version (and upgrade later after relevant testing time) or delay your release to allow the extra testing time needed.

Comment: @DavidSpillett as in the case with the next Debian release, [which has been delayed](https://lwn.net/Articles/678770/) to accommodate an LTS kernel probably becoming available.