# Linux 5.8 --> 5.13 Kernel Update

Tags: kernel

Is is possible to update my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Linux Kernel 5.8.x to the latest stable 5.13 kernel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761879/why-doesnt-the-latest-ubuntu-edition-come-with-the-latest-stable-linux-kernel-v?rq=1

Comment: Possible, but not recommended and on your own risk. Better stick with any of the kernel versions officially supported with your version.

Comment: @vanadium In my opinion, the risk is slight. If the latest mainline kernel is installed and doesn't work correctly in every respect, one may select the older kernel version, for example 5.8, at the GRUB menu and boot correctly.